# Relative Center in Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am using Autolayout to position my Views.
In my case, that is a `UILabel` on top and a `UIStackView` below it.
The `UIStackView` is configured for `.fill` and all it's `arrangedSubviews` have a correct `heightConstraint`.
What I want to do is add Constraints so that the `UIStackView` is vertically centred in the space between `myLabel.bottomAnchor` & `mySuperview.bottomAnchor`.

What I tried so far is:

- Adding top & bottom Constraint for `UIStackView`:

  - `_stackView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: _myLabel.bottomAnchor)`
  - `_stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: _mySuperview.bottomAnchor)`

Now this works in that it just puts the correctly sized `UIStackView` at the bottom of `_mySuperview`.

What I want however is it to be in the centre. 
I saw there is a method called `anchorWithOffset(to:)` which sounds like exactly what I need but could not find the correct way to use it.

So my question is, how do I centre a `UIView` between two given `NSLayoutAnchors`?

*Edit: I am aware of the fact that I could just add a `UIView` that is constraint between my two other views and centre my `UIStackView` in there. I am however looking for a purer solution.*

Comment: I missed your _"Edit"_ while answering. Not sure what you mean by a "purer" solution

Comment: By "purer" I meant by only using the proper constraints, without the use of additional views. While your answer does indeed work I am looking more for the correct use of AutoLayout in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next code does the trick:

```
let dimensionBefore = _myLabel.bottomAnchor.anchorWithOffset(to: _stackView.centerYAnchor)
let dimensionAfter = _stackView.centerYAnchor.anchorWithOffset(to: _mySuperview.bottomAnchor)
dimensionBefore.constraint(equalTo: dimensionAfter, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```

But this works only since iOS 10

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to achieve this in code rather than in storyboard/xib, but these are often really useful to test out autolayout ideas - once you've got it working in a storyboard it'll then be clear what code you need to write to do the same.

You could achieve this by using an additional vertical `UIStackView` to wrap the `UIStackView` that you want.

In the example below, I added empty `UIView`s above and below the inner `UIStackView`, and set the outer one to **Fit Proportionally**

[image]

**Alternatively…**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive example! I am however looking for a solution that does not makes use of additional views.